# How do I encode WebVTT document as UTF-8 and MIME type="text/vtt"?

Tags: accessibility, mime-types, html5-video, html5-audio, closed-captions

"A WebVTT file must consist of a WebVTT file body encoded as UTF-8 and labeled with the MIME type text/vtt."
whatwg source: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/webvtt.html

i figure i need to set .htaccess? i'm on apache/php/mysql.

Comment: Did you mean to ask how do you configure mime types for apache web server? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/913869/how-to-change-the-default-encoding-to-utf-8-for-server] and [http://www.i18nguy.com/markup/serving.html#tip01] might be of use to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `AddDefaultCharset ISO-8859-1` with `AddDefaultCharset UTF-8` in the *Apache.conf* file.

If using *.htaccess* for configuration use something similar to:

```
<Files unicode-example-intro.html>
AddType "text/html; charset=UTF-8" html
</Files>
```