# Whitespace if I scroll up (HTML)

Tags: jquery, html, css

This bug doesn't show up in jsFiddle but on my local machine in Chrome, if I scroll up, there's about a small but noticeable whitespace with one random character in the top left : https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkYD3.jpg

I've attached the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TJ9SB/) but it doesn't seem to have the bug. I'm not sure what's going wrong here; for what it's worth, the bug also appears in DreamWeaver.

Code:

```
*{margin: 0; padding: 0;}
#slide-1 .bcg {
background-image:url('http://wanderingdanny.com/oxford/images/p/b4242667-wytham-woods-avenue.jpg'); 
background-position: center center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: cover;
height: 700px;
width: 100%;
position:relative;
 }

 #slide-1 .hsContainer {
display: table;
table-layout: fixed;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
position: fixed;
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0)
}


 #slide-1 .hsContent {
max-width: 450px;
margin: -150px auto 0 auto;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
color: #ebebeb;
padding: 0 8%;
text-align: center;

 }
```

Comment: Looks like it might be a BOM. Encode your document properly.

Comment: Try removing everything other than this code or the code your pasted in the fiddle and see if it works

Comment: You might want to checkout: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518572/utf-8-html-without-bom-displays-strange-characters

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I'm not sure what you mean