# marathi language not shown properly in browser

Tags: html, css, utf-8, character-encoding, lang

In my html document, I have my html as:

```
<html>
<head><title>title</title></head>

<body>  <div>विजय कदम</div>   </body>
</html>
```

I am getting output as:

```
à¤µà¤¿à¤œà¤¯ à¤•à¤¦à¤®
```

Any idea? what do I need to specify?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Save your file in [UTF-8 encoding](https://superuser.com/questions/21135/how-can-i-edit-unicode-text-in-notepad)
2. Add meta tag to the html to support UTF-8
3. Make sure your server supports UTF-8 encoding, an [example for Apache](http://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CGwQFjAB&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913869/how-to-change-the-default-encoding-to-utf-8-for-server&ei=9ZAzUO2yKoST0QWU14CIBg&usg=AFQjCNFtHGcTksYfV_ULSx4CyZgXrsxFxg&sig2=rDodpiIy62x1QJ-A7K5otA).

How to change the page encoding to [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8):

Add the following tag to the HTML:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
```

Or the HTML5 equivalent:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

for more information about characters encoding check [this out](http://kunststube.net/encoding/).

Answer (score 2):

You need an editor that saves in Unicode UTF-8.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
```

you can also use a converter to display hindi. link: http://vikku.info/indian-language-unicode-converter/hindi-unicode-converter.html what you do is, you paste html text. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

use lang="hi" inside the div tag

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).