# Ideas to get around a Character Encoding mismatch

Tags: html, character-encoding

I get this validation warning when I try and validate my page.

> The character encoding specified in the HTTP header (iso-8859-1) is
>   different from the value in the  element (utf-8). I will use the
>   value from the HTTP header (iso-8859-1) for this validation.

Here is the encoding set for the file:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

If I try and use characters like ĉĵŝĝ (iso-8859-3 compatible) they are rendered incorrectly. I think this is an issue with the server in my college because it is using the version one of the Latin encoding (iso-8859-1).

Is there a way I can get round this (if the problem lies with the encoding set with the college's server)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also set this option in your `.htaccess` file

```
<FilesMatch "\.(htm|html|xhtml|php)$">
    AddDefaultCharset utf-8
</FilesMatch>
```

That way, all the files with the above extensions will be served with utf-8 instead of iso-8859-1

Bye

Answer (score 0):

*Saluton,*
you could try `.xhtml`. Maybe the college's server then uses another header. The other way is to use HTML entities for the Esperanto letters `&#...;`.

As the HTTP headers are normative, and not the HTML meta, you are stuck when you cannot change the server's config.

[Another solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913869/how-to-change-the-default-encoding-to-utf-8-for-server) proposes a local directory for your .html with a httpd.conf file.