# What is the best configuration defaultCharSet in hosting server?

Tags: apache, character-encoding, webserver, cloud-hosting

In my hosting, there are different charset were using by my customer (utf-8, iso-8859-1 etc).

If I configured like this:

```
AddDefaultCharset "utf-8"
```

another customers (who using charset except utf-8) have got charset problems. They web pages doesn't show good.

If I configured like this:

```
AddDefaultCharset "iso-8859-1"
```

another customer have proglem.

What is the best solution? Why don't the all browser see right charset in html head tag?

Comment: I configured: `AddDefaultCharset off` And problem is solved. Will this config create any problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to change the default encoding to UTF-8 for server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/913869/how-to-change-the-default-encoding-to-utf-8-for-server)

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. In the future, please ask questions like this there.