# How to Print special characters in PHP

Tags: php

I have a code like below

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8');
echo 'Welcome to Loréal Website';
```

When I try to print this content in browser it coming é in Loréal is deformed.

[image]

How to solve this issue ?

Thanks for Reply

Comment: Ref link :http://kunststube.net/encoding/

Comment: I changed my charset to charset=windows-1252 Now its working

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your source file is actually encoded in `UTF-8`.

Comment: Thanks for Reply How to check that

Comment: It depends on your editor/platform.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your browser is configured with UTF-8 Encoding.

Usually under View-> Encoding -> UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

Configure the editor you are using to write the PHP to save in UTF-8.

The problem is because you are claiming the data is UTF-8 when it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Please be sure the php file you have created is in utf8 charset. Also check if utf8 encoding is supported/configured by your web server.

See this link in case you have apache https://stackoverflow.com/a/913885/1716962

Comment: The default encoding emitted by a server doesn't matter when you are stating it explicitly in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try:

```
echo htmlentities('Welcome to Loréal Website');
```