# jQuery / AJAX / php encoding nightmare

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, encoding, utf-8

First of all, my database encoding is utf-8.

I must send the string `Fußball` to `index.php` via the `POST` method. When I send it using an HTML form with `action="index.php"`, it is sent as `Fu%DFball` and to return it correctly I use `htmlentities()` on the php file. It works great. The problem starts when I try to send it using jQuery/AJAX.

```
$("#Form").submit(function() {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType : "text",
    url: "index.php", //Does the validation
    data: $("#Form").serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data)
    },
});
return false;
});
```

It is sent as `Fu%C3%9Fball` and returned as `FuÃ` and I tried everything to decode it or send it in a different way. Here is what is returned in various scenarios:

Sending normally, with `htmlentities()` on the php file:

```
FuÃ
```

Sending normally, without `htmlentities()` or with `htmlspecialchars()` on the php file

```
FuÃŸball
```

Sending normally, with `utf8_decode()` on the php file

```
Fu
```

Using `escape()`, `encodeURIComponent()` or `contentType: "utf-8"` on the jQuery script before sending the string makes the form to be submitted in a way the `.php` file can't understand, but not only that, it still sends the string as `Fu%C3%9Fball`.

I also used the proper command for each file type to encode all my documents as `utf-8`, which didn't make any difference so I assume it was all `utf-8` to start with.

Comment: First of all, get rid of all `htmlentities()` calls  - this needs to be fixed at the root, creating entities will not be necessary. What is your *page* encoding? Looks like it might not be UTF-8. Can you make it UTF-8?

Comment: Should be utf-8 as well. I added `mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");` when doing the tests to see if that was the problem and it didn't make a difference.

Comment: look in your browser's "encoding" menu when opening the page. That's the final word on what encoding is used

Comment: Oddly enough it wasn't utf-8. I changed it using `header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` this time and the problem was solved. Any ideas on why it wasn't utf-8 by default? My locale is utf-8, I never set anything different from that...

Comment: I added an answer. You probably need to look at the server settings for the default content type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your web *page's* encoding is also UTF-8.

If it is ISO-8859-1 by default, it'll parse UTF-8 characters wrongly, as experienced by you.

To check, look in your browser's "encoding" menu when opening the page: That's the final word on what encoding is used.

It could be that your server is configured to output ISO-8859-1 content type headers for HTML files. See [How to change the default encoding to UTF-8 for Apache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913869/how-to-change-the-default-encoding-to-utf-8-for-server) for how to fix that.