# utf-8 characters not displaying in chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap, utf-8

Having an issue with html special characters not displaying correctly in chrome see

[Example Page](http://sandbox.dev.activemls.com/agent/)

I have gone through and resaved every file in the project as utf-8 confirmed my meta tag deceleration and confirmed that chrome is set to default to utf-8. No issues in firefox or ie. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Im pulling my hair out.

Comment: It seems to display fine for me in Chrome.  Where on the page do the incorrect characters get displayed?

Comment: I see this <<Full Time RealtorÂ®>> instead of <<Full Time Realtor®>>

Comment: I see the same problem as @SandraWillford. Chrome 26.0.1410.64

Comment: Same problem with part of russian UTF-8 characters. Only in chrome.

Answer (score 4):

How about setting the page to be UTF-8?

It's currently:

```
Content-Type:text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
```

Which if you're using Apache: [How to change the default encoding to UTF-8 for Apache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913869/how-to-change-the-default-encoding-to-utf-8-for-server)

Comment: from my shell.html 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

Comment: Whatever webserver you are using (you haven't said which) is setting a header('Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1'); which is sent before the HTML is started.

Comment: Ok, so how do i fix this in my html? so that the encoding is correct?

Comment: Our web server is a privately maintained box.

Comment: You can't fix it in the HTML. Whatever software you're using as a webserver needs to be told to send the header content-type with UTF-8. What software for a web server are you using?

Comment: server is running LAMP and PYTHON. This is a new issue however as on all our other sites it works fine. Switching to an html5 doc type or using twitter bootstrap are the only two new variables?

Comment: From our server admin re: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/913869/how-to-change-the-default-encoding-to-utf-8-for-server
 
That directive only does anything when Apache itself is generating the
page, which isn't the case here. Cherrypy is generating the page, and
Apache is just passing it through. Cherrypy does use utf-8 already,
but the version of cherrypy on dev has a bug that affects the
transmission of the content-type header.

So I need a work around!

Answer (score 3):

Set browser default encoding to UTF-8:

**go to Settings->Show advanced settings->Customize fonts, set Encoding to Unicode(UTF-8)**

Tested at chrome Version 42.0.2311.90 (64-bit)

Comment: This option doesn't appear in Chrome 49. [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/9dpE6bw.png)

Answer (score 3):

As of mid-2017, it appears Chrome has removed the manual encoding menu, you now need to download a Chrome extension to manually change it.

See this post: https://superuser.com/questions/1160003/how-do-i-change-the-character-encoding-for-a-webpage-in-chrome