# can't use some words in meta tags in Persian

Tags: html, meta

I want to use meta tags for description of the website. But unfortunately some words don't show up. Instead of their words it shows `?`

How can I fix this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you set charset meta tag to 'UTF-8'?

Comment: @jmosawy Yeah. But nothing changed

Comment: Does it occur only for some specific words or everything is just showing up as '???'

Comment: @jmosawy No. Not every words. One alphabet or two.

Comment: Can you give me some examples? Are you using special letters like 'ی' in your words? Btw, let me know about your OS and the OS region settings.

Answer (score 0):

try to add this in your html `<head>` tag

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Comment: I added this code in header of the site and also upper line of that meta description code. But nothing changed

Comment: are you able to see this "symbols" somewhere else? The command tells the browser to use that kind of encoding to read the document, maybe is your browser/machine that is not able to render them (watch this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16658463/utf-8-characters-not-displaying-in-chrome)

Comment: I don't think so if it's about the browser, cause it shows same result in different browsers.