# Why do I get a different result using the same data?

Tags: php, mysql, apache

While moving my websites to a new server, a found the following issue: the rendering of 'strange' characters (ê,ç,ã,etc) coming from mysql are being rendered wrong.

For example:

MySQL: Galo vai a final, apÃ³s cobranÃ§as de pÃªnaltis.

**Old server (apache 2.2 /php 5.3):** 
Galo vai a final, após cobranças de pênaltis. (Correct)

**New server (apache 2.4 /php 5.4):** 
Galo vai a final, apÃ³s cobranÃ§as de pÃªnaltis. (Wrong)

I belive that either apache or php is causing this but I haven't found documentantion about it anywhere.

Can someone help me to find the cause for this error?

**EDIT**

Here's the code to render this (note that it's the same in both servers):

Controller:

```
//Noticias
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->select("id,titulo,thumb,conteudo")
    ->from('noticia')
    ->limit(10)
    ->where("data <= '$today'")
    ->andWhere("status = 1")
    ->andWhere("categoria_id = 1")
    ->orderby('data DESC');
$res = $q->fetchArray();
foreach($res as $key => $value){
    $res[$key]['titulo'] = stripslashes($res[$key]['titulo']);
    $res[$key]['conteudo'] = strip_tags($res[$key]['conteudo']);
    $res[$key]['conteudo'] = stripslashes($res[$key]['conteudo']);
    $res[$key]['conteudo'] = substr($res[$key]['conteudo'],0,150) . '...';
}
$smarty -> assign('noticias',$res);
```

View:

```
<ul class="homelist">
    {foreach item=noticia from=$noticias name=news}
     <li> <a href="noticia/{$noticia.id}/{$noticia.titulo|slug}/"><img src="assets/images/noticias/{$noticia.thumb}" alt="" /></a> <a class="title" href="noticia/{$noticia.id}/{$noticia.titulo|slug}/">{$noticia.titulo}</a>
      <p>{$noticia.conteudo}</p>
      <a class="more" href="noticia/{$noticia.id}/{$noticia.titulo|slug}/">more</a> 
    </li>   
    {/foreach} 
    <li><p align="center"><a href="/noticias/1">Veja mais</a></p> </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: incorrect encoding. check the encoding settings in apache

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php#112476
`As of PHP 5.4 they changed default encoding from "ISO-8859-1" to "UTF-8"` worth looking into as a possible cause?

Comment: Do you have a content type specified in the html? Something like: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">`

Comment: @Flosculus I believe he is just echoing the string.

Comment: Maybe this answer is helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/913869/how-to-change-the-default-encoding-to-utf-8-for-server

Comment: @Flosculus This change only applies to the encoding of special characters that cannot directly be displayed in HTML like `&` or `>`.

Comment: @joe776 fair enough, i was just looking into any changes to character encoding in 5.4

Comment: See [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/a/279279).

Comment: @Lex, I have <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> in the code.

Comment: @silentw, if I change utf-8 to 8859, the rest of the page goes wrong and the parts that are already wrong get worse, like: Galo vai a final, apÃƒÂ³s cobranÃƒÂ§as de pÃƒÂªnaltis.

Comment: You are seing UTF-8 characters interpreted in a single-byte encoding (perhaps ISO-8859-1).Either your database was reimported wrong (original dump was UTF-8 and it was imported in a ISO-something encoding), or you are reading correct UTF-8 data and interpret it as something else. Please show us your test code.

Comment: @RandomSeed, I added code to the question but I don't think it'll help since it's the same on both servers. Also, the database is the same in both too.

Comment: It sure helps, because there we can see that you use an external library to access your database. Those who know about it will likely be able to advise the relevant settings to verify (I am afraid I have no clue).

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the encoding manually to "ISO-8859-1". Before 5.4, the default encoding was "UTF-8".
Use this code:

```
htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_COMPAT,'ISO-8859-1', true)
```

Comment: As I said, he probably is only just echoing the string, not using `htlmspecialchars`. In my experience, the correct charset in the meta tags is enough.

Comment: `htmlspecialchars` does not apply here. It only applies to e.g. `<` or   `>` not special characters of the language. And it's the other way round: Now the default encoding is UTF-8, before 5.4 it was ISO-8859-1