# Getting Arabic Query String in Question Marks

Tags: php

I am getting a a request like this and the url looks like this : http://domain.com/page.php?text={Arabic Word}

Now am trying to get the text using $_GET['text'] but i keep getting it like "????????" , whats the problem

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
    include('EnTransliteration.class.php');
    $tr = new EnTransliteration();

    $str = iconv( "utf-8//TRANSLIT//IGNORE","windows-1256",  $_GET['text']);
    $en_str = $tr->ar2en($str);

    $string = <<<XML
    <root>
    <translation>$en_str</translation>
    </root>
    XML;

    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string);
    header('Content-type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8');
    echo $xml->asXML();
    ?>
```

Comment: I am having the same problem but can't find solution yet :( Did you solve this problem? Pls advise

Answer (score 0):

Your Apache server probably doesn't accept UTF-8 URL encoding. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913869/how-to-change-the-default-encoding-to-utf-8-for-server) answer to solve your problem.

Hope it will help :)

Comment: i tried it and i tryed the one for the .htaccess file and still nothing is changed

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML form needs to explicitly declare that the data must be sent as UTF-8. Otherwise, it will use the user's locale, which may not mean windows-1256, and certainly doesn't mean UTF-8.

e.g.

```
<form action="" method="get" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

Comment: am not getting the request from a form the request is as this url  http://domain.com/page.php?text={Arabic Word}

Comment: You mean you type it directly in the browser's address bar?!? Well, in that case, you're receiving the input as Windows-1256 or whatever the OS locale is. The only way to "kind of" receive UTF-8 is to ask users to use URL encoding, which would obviously be very inconvinient for "direct to browser" typing. If you're using file_get_contents("http://..."), you can use rawurlencode() over the UTF-8 content.

Comment: @boen_robot It works for me on Chrome and Safari, but I am getting question marks in IE, Opera and Firefox. Is there away to get it working on all browsers by entering the Arabic text on the address bar direct?

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can help :

```
<?php
      $title = 'أبجد هوز';
      $path1 = '/product/'.rawurlencode($title);
      echo $path1."<br>";
      $path2 = rawurldecode($path1);
      echo $path2;
  ?>
```

Comment: this is true but am not the one who is sending the request

Answer (score -1):

1-open start

2-open notepad

3-write your code

4-when you saving file make Encoding: utf-8

5-file name name.html name.php

Comment: You don't seem to know what he is talking about... You are talking about the file encoding, besides, he's getting a result, so he ran the script in a web server :)