# Browser displaying page in UTF-8 instead of windows-1251

Tags: apache, encoding, character-encoding, cp1251

I have a website, it contains html only, and there is a lot of cyrillic symbols.
Browser is setting the UTF-8 encoding, instead of windows-1251, like it should be. So, english letters displays fine, but every cyrillic symbols is like ����

Here is my setup:
RHEL 6.3 (2.6.32-279.el6.x86_64)
Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)

Here is my **.htaccess** file:

```
Options +Includes 
AddDefaultCharset WINDOWS-1251
```

First lines of the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Company name, etc</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=WINDOWS-1251">
```

Example page on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/gwTZVHMj) or [phpfiddle for those who don't have access to pastebin](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/5r7-ysk)

So, charset is set everywhere, and if I mannualy change the encoding in the browser to windows-1251 - it displays just fine, but autodetect sets the utf-8, and I don't know why.
If it helps - site was hosted on Sun OS 5.10 before.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: share full code in jsfiddle

Comment: Maybe this answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/913869/how-to-change-the-default-encoding-to-utf-8-for-server

Comment: @samankhademi I simplified the question by removing all javascript code - it obviosly had no effect on this, because the problem still appears. here is the code http://pastebin.com/gwTZVHMj

Comment: @Qben thanks for trying, but it didn't

Comment: @Alexander i'm in iran and pastebin.com filtered ;( for us upload in fiddle

Comment: @samankhademi it appears to me that jsfiddle refuses to accept the html tags. [is this opens?](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/5r7-ysk)

Comment: i see some frogs & Crabs!!! what is your language ? arabic ?

Comment: No, russian. But in the fiddle its not displaying correcly too. i just copied it from html file.

Comment: why you don't use iso-8859-1??? Russian also use it!

Comment: It's not me who wrote this site, so right now the question is how do I make it right with what I have.

Comment: @samankhademi Russians don't use IO-8859-1
Aleksander: Does it happen in all browsers? What are the HTTP headers? What is raw data stream from server to client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I **commented out** the following line in `httpd.conf`, restarted httpd and everything displays correct now:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

Comment: Is there any other way than modifying `httpd.conf`?

Comment: @AndrewBest I can't say

Comment: thanks for the answer. I had suffered from the same problem for a long time. wondering who came with the idea to leave this setting in httpd uncommented.