# getting special characters in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I'm at begginner level of mysql, doing transition from access to mysql
got a very simple routine running, inserting some data from simple phpform into localhost base.
i ran into a problem with some slavic characters like čšž as they don't display right

- got mysql base set to utf-8 encoding and if i input directly it works ok
- got all meta data set to
- got this after connection

  mysql_query("SET NAMES ''utf8'' COLLATE ''utf8_slovenian_ci''");
  mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET ''utf8_slovenian_ci'';");

Still get gibberish like this ÄÄ‡Å¾Ä‘Å¡p or this Å¡pela

Any ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with UTF-8, you have to make sure that *everything* is setup to use UTF-8.

You correctly enabled UTF-8 in the database (make sure that also the column is set to use UTF-8; in my opinion, it's best to use utf8_bin - faster at sorting and less country-specific).
However, what about the web server?

Make sure your pages are using UTF-8, with the correct meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Additionally, it wouldn't hurt to set the web server to use UTF-8 too: see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913869/how-to-change-the-default-encoding-to-utf-8-for-server), for example.

Eventually, remember that PHP 5 *per se* does NOT work with Unicode. As such, you must be *extremely careful* when using string functions, such as strencode, substr, etc. Some string functions have support for Unicode (see their documentation). In other cases, you may use [mbstring](https://www.php.net/mbstring) functions.

Comment: tx, had all tha enabled, i guess. I changed mysql_query line to mysql_query("set names 'utf8'"); and it solved my problems

Comment: this line in place of previous query solved my problems