# Extjs4 Sending accented characters to the server

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2, extjs-mvc

I am working with Extjs4. I am trying to send accented characters to server. I was trying to send ó. And what I was receiving at the server side was Ã³. I am sending it using Store proxy. In store proxy, I have added

```
headers: {
                          'Content-Type': 'charset=utf-8'
         }
```

Still it did not send the accented characters properly. How should I send accented characters to the server? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

user2316489, IMHO this is a problem with your server configuration, rather than a front-end application. [Check how to change your server charset.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913869/how-to-change-the-default-encoding-to-utf-8-for-server)