# Consume soapWebservice HTTP_URL_POST_STMF_XML. Big XML > 65K

Tags: xml, soap, ibm-midrange, rpgle

I'm trying to call a "HTTP_URL_POST_STMF_XML", because the soap string that we have it could be bigger than 65500 characters.

My problem is that I don't know how to call it right. Always the call HTTP_URL_POST_STMF_XML  return to me "500".

My call is the next one:

> rc = HTTP_URL_POST_STMF_XML(
>                       %trim(urlWS)
>                     : %TRIM(filename)
>                     : *NULL
>                     : %paddr(Incoming)
>                     : %addr(Incoming)
>                     : HTTP_TIMEOUT
>                     : HTTP_USERAGENT
>                     : 'text/xml'
>                     : 'actionWS');

also I Tried to use the exercise nº 7 of Scott Klement but I don't know how to use. 
what I am doing wrong?

In the debug file "/tmp/httpapi_debug.txt" I have this response:

> "ç?ËÈ
>   íËÁÊ  ÅÁ>È  ÇÈÈø /øÑ
>   ä?>ÈÁ>È è`øÁ  ÈÁÌÈ Ì_%
>   ë! & ÄÈÑ?>  øÊ?ÄÁËËëÇÑø_Á>È!ÊÀÁÊäÊÁ/ÈÁ
>   ä?>ÈÁ>È <Á>ÅÈÇ
>
> ```
>                                                                         ËÁ>ÀÊ/Ï    Á>ÈÁÊÁÀ
> ```
>
> PARUNIC
>   
>   8001-255666-P-1-9
>   Á>ÈÁÊÁÀ                                                         çèè&
>   ñ>ÈÁÊ>/% ëÁÊÎÁÊ áÊÊ?Ê                                          à/ÈÁ 
>   ëÍ>     àÁÄ               å(è
>   ä?>ÈÁ>È è`øÁ  ÈÁÌÈ Ì_%  ÄÇ/ÊËÁÈ ÍÈÃ
>   èÊ/>ËÃÁÊ á>Ä?ÀÑ>Å  ÄÇÍ>,ÁÀ
>
> ```
>                                                                         ëÁÈáÊÊ?Ê   J    çèè&         ñ>ÈÁÊ>/% ëÁÊÎÁÊ áÊÊ?Ê
> ```
>
> "

Regards

Comment: I believe this could help you.

Éxito

[Extjs4 Sending accented characters to the server][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25787764/extjs4-sending-accented-characters-to-the-server/25811838#25811838

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a 500 is usually an issue with the server, but in this case I wonder if it is a character encoding issue.  What is the CCSID of the stream file?  WRKLNK and see what the CCSID is.  Also, make sure the very first characters are `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`  There should be nothing else: not a space, not a carriage return, nothing.  You can look at the file in hex with DSPF to see what is in there.

Comment: Hello Buck! The first characters are ok. The file starts without any blank space. the XML file starts with "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>" and the file in my ifs has "CCSID =   284".

Comment: 284 is Spanish EBCDIC.  The web site almost certainly wants either ASCII or UTF-8.  UTF-8 is CCSID 1208.  If Scott's API doesn't do the conversion, try creating your file with CCSID 1208.

Comment: Ok, but I can't create a file with this CCSID (1208). I'm creating a file like this. fd = open('/tmsclxml/vITEMws6.xml' 
: O_WRONLY+O_CREAT+O_TEXTDATA      
: O_RDWR                           
: 1208); but in the properties of this file appears "ID de juego de caracteres codificados  :   284 " the spanish code (284) I don't know how to change/create it ¿?

Comment: ok, I had seen that I need one more parameter "O_CCSID" to indicate the new CSSID. Thank you for your help one more time!!

Comment: One more thing: I think that if you write to an existing file, yu keep the file's original CCSID.  You can't change it with open() - you need to delete it (maybe with unlink()) and re-create it with open().