# Font not displaying properly in spanish

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a web page displaying inside an iframe when I access it from from local machine:

http://localhost/mypage.html

it will display the following text correctly in spanish:

Búsqueda

But if I call it from my website

http://mywebsiteurl.com/mypage.html

I get the following:

BÃºsqueda

notice the ú has been replaced by Ãº I have tried changing fonts but the results are the same. The files on the web server are the same as on my localhost. Any ideas? Could it have something to do with my apache or php configuration may be difrerent than on my localhost machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need might be

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

in your .htaccess

For more insight check this thread [How to change the default encoding to UTF-8 for Apache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913869/how-to-change-the-default-encoding-to-utf-8-for-server)

Comment: Thanks! that fixed it :)

Comment: Also I found if you don't have access to your httpd.conf file to add the AddDefaultCharset UTF-8 you can add <meta charset="utf-8"> to the <head> section of your html file.

Answer (score 1):

in your html tag  add the following

```
<html lang="es">
```