# Latin Character's not working properly with PHP and Sessions

Tags: php, rest, session, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I am having problems with Latin accent characters and php sessions. The quickest illustration is this sample code...

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["string_value"] = "CÉSARS";

echo($_SESSION["string_value"]);
```

When this executes it returns..

> CÃ‰SARS

I found I can do this and it works

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["string_value"] = mb_convert_encoding("CÉSARS", 'ISO-8859-1','UTF-8');
echo($_SESSION["string_value"]);
```

Problem is that in the actual application I am getting data from a REST service that is loading objects/data that are being used by the application and stored in session. I am hoping someone might have some way to make this all work in a seamless manner so that I can just use the objects returned by the REST service without having to run it through a conversion. Both when drawing to the screen and when using in further REST calls.

Any ideas? Searching hasn't returned much on this, was hoping it was some php.ini setting.

Comment: Make sure that your page is rendering using the same charset that you're receiving from this REST service.... PHP doesn't have any problems with charsets in session/browser/editor/etc as long as you're consistent

Comment: It's quite possible that the issue isn't PHP, but is your server (apache, etc.) - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/913869/how-to-change-the-default-encoding-to-utf-8-for-server

Comment: AddDefaultCharset utf-8   fixed the issue mentioned...