# HTTP Basic Authentication fail with password with non iso-8859-1 characters

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, safari, basic-authentication, windows-1252

I have a problem with Basic Authentication. The server was an **Apache httpd server 2.2.12** and I have created a location protected by basic auth:

```
<Location /basictest>
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "BasicAuth di Test"
    AuthBasicProvider file
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/basictest.passwords
    Require valid-user
</Location>
```

In the password file /etc/apache2/basictest.passwords I have defined two:

**user:password**

```
pippo:pippo£
kanji:誰か確認上記これらのフ
```

If I test the access with **Chrome (47.x)** all works fine, but if I test the link with **Firefox (43.x)** or with **Safari Web Browser on iOS(Safari/601.1)** the authentication failed because the base64 encoding of user:password use a wrong character set (Windows-1252)! In Chrome test case the character set used was UTF-8

```
Chrome ---------> cGlwcG86cGlwcG/Cow==
Safari/FireFox -> cGlwcG86cGlwcG+j
```

In the meantime we waiting https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7617 implementations, **can I force FireFox and Safari to use UTF-8 on base64 encryption as Chrome's behavior?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont sure if its a bug because browsers work with different encode/chars.

Already use UTF-8 anyway:

```
 - Opera 10  
 - Chrome
```

Uses a different encoding but has no problem with req param (so ASCII is still OK):

```
Firefox 1-4  (UTF-16 lower bytes)
Safari 4-5   (ISO-8859-1)
IE:Mac 5     (MacRoman)
IE 5-8       (CP_ACP)
IEMobile 6-8 (CP_ACP)
Netscape 4   (CP_ACP)
Opera 5      (CP_ACP)
```

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=41489#c90

About his doubts.
The Basic authentication does not provide support for non-ISO-8859-1 characters.

You can try to convert the characters in .htaccess to UTF8, not tested, not sure if it works. [How to change the default encoding to UTF-8 for Apache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913869/how-to-change-the-default-encoding-to-utf-8-for-server)

I recommend using another authentication method or create a login page.

If other colleagues have a better solution, please let me know.