# PHP UK £ symbol inconsistency

Tags: php

I have 2 similar PHP pages, one displays the UK £ symbol correctly, the other displays a black diamond with a ? in it.

In order to diagnose the problem I cut the code down and they are now identical, but still display differently.  How can that be???
This is the code
`

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-gb">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf8">
</head>

<body>
<?php
echo '<p>';

echo "£"."123";

?>
</body>

</html>`
```

While working with the original code it seemed that I could fix one by removing the charset=utf8 but if I removed it from the other it prefixed the £ with a capital A with an accent.

What is happening here?

Comment: Your text encoding is in some way messed up. You're declaring `charset=utf8`. Make sure that your charset *really is* UTF-8. Check in your text editor.

Comment: Perhaps the actual files saved to disk with different encodings?

Comment: Look at the Content-Type (and Content-Encoding) **http** headers from your two servers.

Comment: Also, you can use `&pound;` in your HTML instead of copying and pasting the pound sign itself

Comment: The two files are both on the same server.  How can I check the encoding of the actual files?

Answer (score 1):

You have configured another charset in your apache configuration. Maybe your php are proccessed with `ISO-8859-1` and you are defining in your HTML `UTF-8`. That's an inconsistency. Try to define `UTF-8` in your apache configuration.

See this post:

[How to change the default encoding to UTF-8 for Apache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913869/how-to-change-the-default-encoding-to-utf-8-for-server)

> In httpd.conf add (or change if it's already there):
>
> `AddDefaultCharset utf-8`

Comment: I have added AddDefaultCharset utf-8 to httpd.conf and rebooted, but the problem is still there.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the issue was occurring was that the PHP files were saved with different encoding. The one which behaved okay had encoding *UTF-8*, while the problematic file had encoding *Windows-1252*.  I use Bluefish and it all looked okay in there, but when I ran the `cat` command on the file I could see the odd character.

Thanks for your help!