# Is it possible to set the Content-type output value for a single folder in Apache?

Tags: php, apache, encoding

My server is set to UTF-8, but i'd like a specific folder to output a Content-Type HTTP header which says charset=Shift-JIS. I tried uploading an .htaccess file to the folder, containing **AddDefaultCharset Shift-jis** but that didn't work.

Comment: What does "folder to be Shift-JIS" mean? That you'd like *its content* to actually be encoded in Shift-JIS? Or that you merely want to output a `Content-Type` HTTP header which says `charset=shift-jis`?

Comment: I was looking for the folder to output a content type HTTP header with charset=Shift-JIS. Thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you place your `AddDefaultCharset` directive in an `htaccess` located in the directory whose Charset you're trying to change?  If not, please do so.

If you want all html files in that directory to have the charset, try

```
<FilesMatch "\.html?$">
    ForceType 'text/html; charset=Shift-jis'
</FileMatch>
```

If that doesn't work, you could set the HTTP header directly with the following directive (in the same `htaccess`)

```
<FilesMatch "\.html?$">
    Header add Content-Type "text/html; charset=Shift-jis"
</FilesMatch>
```

You may need to add more `FileMatch` containers for other file types, and adjust the MIME type within the header (eg: "text/css" or "application/javascript" for `.css` and `.js` files)

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I did. I've tried uploading the htaccess file directly in the folder that I wanted encoded in Shift-jis. I'll give your recommendation a try.

Comment: The first one worked nicely.
<FilesMatch "\.html?$">
    ForceType 'text/html; charset=Shift-jis'
</FileMatch>

Answer (score 0):

According to @MiffTheFox Yes.

```
<Files ~ "\.html?$">  
     Header set Content-Type "text/html; charset=utf-8"
</Files>
```

please look at the original answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/913880/1431184