# Application servers and static files character encoding

Tags: java, html, jakarta-ee, web-applications, server

I woud like to improve my understanding on how
Java Application Servers handle files encodning.

In my understanding Application servers have to be able to correctly read our
static files:
`.html`,`.js`,`.css`, etc.
in order to serve them to the browser.
So here's where the character encoding comes to play:
files encoded in a certain encoding are loaded by the application servers.

My question is:
Does JEE specification dictates what the character encoding
of these files must be ?
Is it configurable ?
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The static resources won't be delivered by your java application as they are static, and will be directly delivered by your web server application. If you deliver the files through a GET handled by your web application, Java can manage the charset programmatically.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913869/how-to-change-the-default-encoding-to-utf-8-for-apache) you can see how to set it for Apache.