# Weird random HTML characters on refresh

Tags: html, web, character

The past month, month and a half, our readers and us (members of the website team) started getting a very weird message when trying to refresh a page or access some parts of the website. We get these screens: [weird characters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soNJM.jpg) and [weird characters also on inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWBoO.jpg). You can also experience the same thing yourself if you try and visit the [website][3].

Has anyone any idea why the website does that or what it might be the problem ? We have changed two development teams until now and no one managed to solve this. At least some help to guide them to the right direction would be nice.

Thank you all.

Comment: It seems to work for me. Which browser do you use ? can you show the header of some of your requests ? My best guess is that your data is sent encrypted (gzip), and the browser doesn't decrypt it properly.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's problem with ur editor read about unicode and utf-8 and change encoding to utf-8 here's e.g [how to change the encoding to uf8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913869/how-to-change-the-default-encoding-to-utf-8-for-server)