# Change Apache LANG to en_GB.UTF-8

Tags: apache, utf-8, ubuntu-16.04

Im looking to change the Apache Environment LANG from C to `en_GB.UTF-8` but cant find where. Inside `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` I added `AddDefaultCharset UTF-8`, [based on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913869/how-to-change-the-default-encoding-to-utf-8-for-apache), restarted apache but the LANG is still set to C.

Running `locale -a` in terminal, I see `en_GB.utf8` and others. How to set the default for apache to `en_GB.UTF-8`?

`set | grep -i utf` shows me `LANG=en_GB.UTF-8`

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Take a look on /etc/apache2/envvars

`## Uncomment the following line to use the system default locale instead:`

`#. /etc/default/local here`