# Python3 logging: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u20ac' when called from apache/php

Tags: php, python-3.x, environment-variables, python-logging

## The question

I have the following simple script:

#### test.py

```python
import logging
import sys

logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.info("€")
```

Depending on the context how this script is called it produces the error:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u20ac' in position 10: ordinal not in range(128)

Why is it doing this and what can I do to fix it?

## What I have already found out

### Observation

When I call this script "normally" it is no problem:

```text
$ python3 test.py 
INFO:root:€
```

However when I create a PHP file /var/www/html/test.php:

```php
<?php
echo "# locale\n\n";
passthru("locale");
echo "\n\n# python\n\n";
passthru("python3 /var/www/html/test.py 2>&1");
```

and then call this file via Apache, it get the error:

```text
$ curl localhost/test.php
# locale

LANG=C
LANGUAGE=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_PAPER="C"
LC_NAME="C"
LC_ADDRESS="C"
LC_TELEPHONE="C"
LC_MEASUREMENT="C"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="C"
LC_ALL=


# python

--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/logging/__init__.py", line 983, in emit
    stream.write(msg)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u20ac' in position 10: ordinal not in range(128)
Call stack:
  File "/var/www/html/test.py", line 5, in <module>
    logging.info("\u20ac")
Message: '\u20ac'
Arguments: ()
```

For comparison this is what I get if I call `locale` directly:

```text
$ locale
LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=de_DE.UTF-8
```

If I change my `passthru`-call in PHP to the following:

```php
passthru("LANG=de_DE.UTF-8 python3 /var/www/html/openWB/test.py 2>&1");
```

then everything works fine.

Where is `LANG=C` coming from? Not from here:

```
cat /etc/default/locale
#  File generated by update-locale
LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_ALL=de_DE.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=de_DE.UTF-8
```

System is Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch).

### Interpretation

Obviously the scripts success is dependent on the settings of my user. I used to think that python scripts are mostly portable across systems. Now I learned they are not even portable from one user to another ;-). Of course it is fine that environment variables change the appearance of the application in question, however it is not so fine that it is guaranteed to break the whole application.

I assume I either need to change my Python script to force UTF-8 (not quite sure why this is not the default behavior if anything else fails anyway) or I need to set the LANG variable for the PHP scripts. For both options the question is: What is the simplest/shortest/most effective way to do that? In best case there is a single option I change to globally fix this for the whole systems. Root access is available.

Note that I am currently stuck on Python 3.5.3 and cannot easily upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55633747/12763954), the `LANG` environment
variable used by Apache is set in /etc/apache2/envvars. The file contains these lines:

```
## The locale used by some modules like mod_dav
export LANG=C
## Uncomment the following line to use the system default locale instead:
#. /etc/default/locale

export LANG
```

The default value is `C`, but, by uncommenting the mentioned line, you can use the system locale instead.

Once it's done, the Python script will inherit the correct locale.

Answer (score 3):

If you are unable to upgrade to python3.7+ (where a UTF-8 mode by default is available even with `LANG=C`):

```
$ LANG=C python3.7 script.py
INFO:root:€
```

and unable to control the environment when the script is called (where you could set `LANG=C.UTF-8` (an agnostic UTF-8 locale) or some other more-specific language-country pair locale):

```
$ LANG=C.UTF-8 python3.5 script.py
INFO:root:€
```

and can't force the encoding via `PYTHONIOENCODING`:

```
$ LANG=C PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8 python3.5 script.py
INFO:root:€
```

then you've got a few gross choices like re-opening the standard streams:

```
$ cat script.py
import locale
import logging
import sys

sys.stdout = open(sys.stdout.fileno(), mode='w', encoding='utf8', buffering=1)
sys.stderr = open(sys.stderr.fileno(), mode='w', encoding='utf8', buffering=1)

logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.info("€")
$ LANG=C python3.5 script.py
INFO:root:€
```

or some sort of redirection / re-exec with the proper environment / locale (though of course, `exec` isn't portable and will only work reasonably well on posixlikes and does not work at all on windows):

```
import os
import locale
import logging
import sys

if os.getenv('PYTHONIOENCODING') != 'UTF-8':
    cmd = [sys.executable, *sys.argv]
    os.execvpe(cmd[0], cmd, {**os.environ, 'PYTHONIOENCODING': 'UTF-8'})

logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.info("€")
$ LANG=C python3.5 script.py
INFO:root:€
```

Comment: `[..]and unable to control the environment when the script is called[..]` I am not necessarily unable. I do have root access to the system in question. I am just unaware where "LANG=C" is coming from. Maybe I can fix that... I would prefer such a "global" solution, because multiple python scripts are affected and if I fix each call individually there is the danger of forgetting one.

Comment: I edited my question to be more specific and added contents of /etc/default/locale.