# Reading special characters in PHP

Tags: php, special-characters

```
$filename = "domainin.txt";

$fp = @fopen($filename, 'r'); 

if ($fp) { 
 $array = explode("\n", fread($fp, filesize($filename)));

}
    $num = count($array);
    for ($i=0;$i<$num;$i++){
    $domains = explode(',', $array[$i]);
    $result[] = $domains;
    }

    foreach($result as $val) {
        if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == $val[0]){
            header ('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
            $host  = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
            $uri   = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/');
            header('Location: '.$val[1]);
            exit(0);
        }
    }
```

I have this which reads a txt file and reroutes URL's. However, a URL has **é** in the address and it won't read it and simply ignores it. How can I force it to read and recognize the special characters?

---

Example of text file is as follows...

```
/path/to/url/original-oné/, /path/to/url/new/
/path/to/url2/original/, /path/to/url2/new/
/path/to/url3/original/, /path/to/url3/new/
```

It's not reading /original-oné/ as the é is like that, it totally skips

Comment: What does `$val` contain ?

Comment: the text file has


/path/to/old/url,/path/to/new/url

Comment: Just a though i think you need to do something with encoding..

Comment: looks like your webserver can't understand the provided url, perhaps [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/913885/374509) could help

Comment: I can't reproduce this on my machine. Is the error in the first `for()` loop or in the second?

Comment: No errors are produced Martin, it simply ignores the letter. For example, if I add a URL with é to the text file, it ignores it and doesn't redirect, however, any URL's without é will redirect as normal.

Comment: @ChrisGwynne Any UTF-8 characters are ASCII encoded and sent as URLs can't contain those symbols as is. Are you sure `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` has the exact string to be matched? Check this in PHP command line and not on browser, as it might render it correctly giving an impression that it is what it is.