# Python encoding issue with mysql.connector - fetching data

Tags: python, encoding, mysql-connector-python

I want to retrieve some data from a dbase. All the tables in it have the utf8_general_ci collation.

By the way, this is a .cgi file, so it is executed by means of an Ajax call.

I'm doing this to make the connection:

```
#!/home/mike/python_venvs/test_venv369/bin/python
...

conn = mysql.connector.connect( host='', database='test_kernel',
                                user='root', password='root',
                                charset='utf8', use_unicode=True )
...
query = ("SELECT * from invoices limit 2")
cursor.execute( query )

for x in cursor:
    print( type( x  )) # is a tuple, i.e. the row
    for y in x:
        print( type( y ) ) # the problem field prints "str"
        if type( y ) == 'str':
            y = y.encode( 'utf-8')
        print( y )
```

On the encoding line above I get:

```
<class 'UnicodeEncodeError'> 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xa3' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

With all the permutations I've tried I get the same thing. '\xa3', by the way, is the '£' character, non-ASCII.

I've tried many different approaches, found mainly here in SO: encode, decode, ... Nothing seems to work. I thought the `str` type was Python 2... but this is definitely a Python3 program, something which I actually checked with `sys.version_info[ 0 ]`!

Comment: What's the the output of `python -c "import locale;print(locale.getpreferredencoding())"`?

Comment: Thanks. I assume this is to be run in the virtual environment stipulated in the shebang at the start of this file, right?  It gives "UTF-8".  Adding shebang line in the question.

Comment: If this is .cgi, then it's being executed by your webserver?  So maybe `su` to the webserver's user (or perhaps root, if root starts the webserver process) and execute the above command as that user.

Comment: Thanks again. Same output for SU. I assume the Apache server process's owner is the SU... but how do I check that? To start and stop I do `sudo systemctl start apache2`.

Comment: Maybe just print `locale.getpreferredencoding()` before you iterate over the query result

Comment: Blow me down with a feather: "pref encoding ANSI_X3.4-1968". What in flip's name is that all about???

Comment: It's a fancy way of saying ASCII*.  I guess you need to try the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913869/how-to-change-the-default-encoding-to-utf-8-for-apache).  *Technically it's a revision of the ASCII standard

Comment: I tried those suggestions, specifically uncommenting `#AddDefaultCharset UTF-8` in /etc/apache2/conf-available/charset.conf. Didn't work. Still getting that preferred encoding.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the help of snakecharmerb's comments, which then led me to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44358390/595305), I found a solution which works:

```
import codecs
sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter('utf-8')(sys.stdout.buffer)
```

I think this constitutes a workaround, and it'd be great if anyone could explain how this setting for `locale.getpreferredencoding()` gets to be set at ASCII/ANSI_X3.4-1968 ... even better if they could then say how to set it to something else.

The culprit is probably Apache, though I'm far from sure.

The [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913869/how-to-change-the-default-encoding-to-utf-8-for-apache) referenced by snakecharmerb unfortunately did not provide a solution for me: I added (or rather uncommented) the following line in /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/charset.conf

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

... and restarted Apache. No change.

**Edit**
Output from various settings for `su` which might be involved:

```
M17A ~ # locale
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_GB:en
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
M17A ~ # echo $LANG
en_GB.UTF-8
M17A ~ # locale charmap
UTF-8
```

I believe it is `su`/root which is indeed running the Apache process.

**Edit 2**
I thought I'd look into the ownership of the processes on my machine. So I ran `ps aux`. Some possibly relevant processes came up which are not owned by me or by root:

```
USER # i.e. owner
...
mysql     1413  0.0  0.1 1419400 16760 ?       Ssl  May15   0:50 /usr/sbin/mysqld
...
www-data  5825  0.0  0.0 143296  5536 ?        S    07:35   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  5826  0.0  0.1 298492 21900 ?        S    07:35   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  5827  0.0  0.1 298096 18700 ?        S    07:35   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  5828  0.0  0.0 296044 15872 ?        S    07:35   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  5829  0.0  0.1 296040 16876 ?        S    07:35   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  5830  0.0  0.0 296052  7972 ?        S    07:35   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
...
www-data  9636  0.0  0.0 296052  7856 ?        S    08:16   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9639  0.0  0.0 295572  6324 ?        S    08:16   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9640  0.0  0.0 295572  6324 ?        S    08:16   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9641  0.0  0.0 295572  6324 ?        S    08:16   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```

Maybe one of these owners is using this ASCII encoding? I wonder how I might find out...

Comment: The root cause is likely that the user that is running the apache process has an ASCII locale (try `su` to that user and execute the `locale` command, also `echo $LANG` and `locale charmap` ).  So the solution probably to change their default locale (but I'm not strong on linux admin, so I don;t want to suggest this as a hard and fast solution)

Comment: I'm not strong on it either. I'll have a go, but all indications are that it is root (i.e. `su`)  which runs the apache process. I'm adding the output from those commands to my answer.