# How to specify no file extension for Apache .htaccess' AddCharset?

Tags: .htaccess

In https://stackoverflow.com/a/25255559/1118719 we see

```
AddCharset utf-8 .html .css .php .txt .js
```

That is marvelous for files named bla.html, bla.css, etc.

But how to match just files named bla?

Sure, one could try e.g.,

```
AddCharset utf-8 .html .txt ""
```

but that doesn't work.

Yes, maybe there is no solution for 'bla' and 'bla.'.

Answer (score 2):

Alas, one must resort to e.g.,

```
<FilesMatch "^[^.]+$">
ForceType 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8'
</FilesMatch>
```